# NASM x86, unexpected result of FIST

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I can't understand a result of fist operation. In my code I'm trying to take 1 integer from user then pass it to assembly, multiple by const and return as an approximated integer.

The problem is that I've read that FIST instruction converts float to integer and saves it in memory. When I return my result AND have int as a type of result i get what i want. However if I change it to float I obtain the result without approximation.
So for 3 and const = 3.86 I expect to get 12 from fist. I compared result in eax with 12 and it seems that there is 12 indeed. However if I change function result type to float I get the 11.58 answer.

The only thing I'm guessing is maybe in the case of returning float its taken from the float stack and because i dont pop it from there this is the answer.

```
extern "C" int fun (int a);

extern "C" float fun (int a);
```

Here's my code:

Assembly

```
section .data
    bmp dd 3.86
    res dd 0

section .text
    global fun

fun:
;---------- intro ---------- 
    push ebp        
    mov ebp,esp     

;-------- procedura -------- 
    fld dword [bmp]     
    fimul dword [ebp+8]
    fist dword [res]
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, [res]

;---------- outro ---------- 

    mov esp, ebp            
    pop ebp                 
    ret
```

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern "C" float fun (int a);

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << fun(a) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"FIST converts ST0 to an integer and stores that in memory;"` [(src)](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-fild.html). You're then getting that value from memory and returning it. It's an integer.

Comment: Ok, so correct me if i'm wrong. If i try to return integer as a float it should be something like x.00000 ( i mean integer with point and zeros ). However I obtain 11.58 instead of 12.000 when i swap float and int in function declaration.

Comment: Depending on what compiler you use, the float result is probably expected on the FP stack by the high-level language, and that's where you left it (also) since you didn't do `FISTP` (pop at the end).

Comment: You're aware that integers and floating-point values are stored *completely* differently in memory, right?

Comment: Ok. So this is what i wanted to know. Thank you. @JonathonReinhart - well... i've actually forgotten about this :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Great point. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl): `"Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIST` does not pop the value from the floating point stack -- it leaves it there.  It just so happens that the normal x86 calling conventions for returning a float value uses the floating point stack -- a function returning float returns with just that single value on the stack.

So when you change the return value of the declaration to `float`, the C code takes that value from the stack and it seems to work fine.  This actually works better than when you declare it as `int` as in the `int` case the C compiler assuming the fp stack is left empty.  Since it was not, if you call your function repeatedly, you'll eventually get an fp stack overflow (which will probably just be ignored, as that's the default behavior, but still).

For a strictly correct program, you should use `FISTP` to convert and pop.